# What does this program basically do? Subtraction of pointers?

Tags: c, string

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i,s;
   s=0;
   char*p;
   for(i=1; i<argc;i++)
   {
      for (p=argv[i];*p;p++);
      s+=(p-argv[i]);
   }
 printf("%d\n",s);
 return 0;
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what does this code does.

As far I see it, it ignores the program's name and for every other string which was printed in the command line it sets `p` to be the current string.

1. The condition `*p` says "travel on `p` as long as it's not `NULL`, i.e until you have reached the end of the string?
2. In each iteration `s` sums the subtraction of the current `p`, the rest of the word, with the name of `argv[i]`, what is the result of this subtraction? Is this the subtraction of the two ascii values?
3. What does this program basically do?

Comment: You can answer all these questions by running the program in a debugger, or by adding print statements to inspect intermediate values of variables.

Comment: Prepare basic inputs.Afterwards, print out all argv, initialize p & i. In order to take more info, print s in nested loop. You will get answers. Or, use gdb

Comment: Determine the total length of the string of arguments.

Comment: Looks like it calculates the size of command line.

Comment: The inner for loop does nothing each iteration, as it's terminated with a semicolon. You need to remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to answering this question is to understand the meaning of this expression:

```
p-argv[i]
```

This is a pointer subtraction expression, which is defined as the distance in sizes of elements pointed to by the pointer between the first and the second pointer. This works when both pointers are pointing to a memory region that has been allocated as a contiguous block (which is true about all C strings in general and the elements of `argv[]` in particular).

The pointer `p` is first advanced to the end of the string (note the semicolon `;` at the end of the loop, which means that the loop body is empty), and then `argv[i]` is subtracted. The result is the length of the corresponding argument.

Comment: the loop terminates with a semicolon. The statement `s+=(p-argv[i]);` runs only once

Comment: @AndyStowAway Yes, I missed the semicolon on the first reading. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @andy no the loop is terminated by the previous semicolon for (p=argv[i];*p;p++); EDIT: missread your answer

Comment: @bigkm That's what Andy meant; there was an edit (invisible now, because I caught it in the first five minutes) where I thought the loop calculates something else.

Comment: I don't get it. Let's assume that the command line is "program abc ed". program is being ignored and then in the first iteration p=abc:
first loop:abc-abc; second loop: bc-abc;third loop" c-abc; so we get -1 plus -2?

Comment: Oh I see now what you're saying about the semicolon. so at the end of "for (p=argv[i];*p;p++);" what would p be exactly? wouldn't it be NULL? so null-the command doesn't give me minus the length?

Comment: @Numerator No, it's not like that: in the first iteration of the outer `for` loop you get to the nested loop, and move `p` to the end of the string `"abc"`, three characters behind the `a`, at the terminating zero. Now subtract the address of `a` from the address of the terminating zero; you will get `3`, because `\0` is three characters behind `a`. That's the length of the first param. The outer loop continues that process for the remaining elements of `argv`, and prints the total length of all arguments.

Comment: @Numerator `p` would not be zero or `NULL`, but what it points to will be zero -- the terminating zero of the C string.

Comment: "move p to the end of the string "abc", three characters behind the a, at the terminating zero", Did you mean after a? the end of the string is "\0" which is three characters  after a, and that is why the loop ends since *p is false (="\0"). so p is "\0". p is has become "/0" and argv[i] hasn't changed, so why don't I get "/o"-"abc"? Im sorry I don't get it.

Comment: @Numerator No, `p` has not become zero, `p` only *points* to zero. For example, if the string `"abc"` starts at the address `5678` in memory, `a` would be at `5678`, `b` at `5679`, `c` at `5680`, and the terminating zero `\0` at `5681`. When the inner loop finishes, `p` would be `5681`, `argv[i]` would be unchanged at `5678`, and the difference would be `5681-5678`, which equals `3`.

Comment: Ahhh I get it with your last comment! Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1):

This code calculates sum of lengths of arguments (as strings) of the program

Answer (score 1):

It tells you the total string length of all the arguments you passed to the program.

In your point (2), it just subtracts the starting address of the string with the address that holds the `\0` character

Answer (score 0):

Its using pointer addresses in a backwards type way to calculate the total characters in all args.

```
for (p=argv[i];*p;p++); //sets p to the address of argv[i]'s \0 terminator
   s+=(p-argv[i]);     // p minus the address of the start of argv[i] accumulated to s
```